# X.509 Why is the signature algorithm added twice in the Attribute Certificate?

Tags: certificates, x.509

As I read some parts of the X.509 specification I found the signature added twice - first in the `AttributeCertificate` as `signatureAlgorithm` and second in the `AttributeCertificateInfo` as `signature`. Could you explain me why? The same goes for the Basic Certificate Fields.

> `signature:` This field MUST contain the same algorithm identifier as the
>      signatureAlgorithm field in the sequence Certificate

```
AttributeCertificate ::= SEQUENCE {
  acinfo               AttributeCertificateInfo,
  signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
  signatureValue       BIT STRING
}

AttributeCertificateInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  version                 AttCertVersion, -- version is v2
  holder                  Holder,
  issuer                  AttCertIssuer,
  signature               AlgorithmIdentifier,
  serialNumber            CertificateSerialNumber,
  attrCertValidityPeriod  AttCertValidityPeriod,
  attributes              SEQUENCE OF Attribute,
  issuerUniqueID          UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
  extensions              Extensions OPTIONAL
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a remnant of some old fears. [Peter Gutmann's X.509 Style Guide](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/x509guide.txt), an old (2001) but instructive read, includes the following paragraph:

> This rather misnamed field contains the algorithm identifier for the signature
>   algorithm used by the CA to sign the certificate.  There doesn't seem to be
>   much use for this field, although you should check that the algorithm
>   identifier matches the one of the signature on the cert (if someone can forge
>   the signature on the cert then they can also change the inner algorithm
>   identifier, it's possible that this was included because of some obscure attack
>   where someone who could convince (broken) signature algorithm A to produce the
>   same signature value as (secure) algorithm B could change the outer,
>   unprotected algorithm identifier from B to A, but couldn't change the inner
>   identifier without invalidating the signature.  What this would achieve is
>   unclear).

So one might infer that, one day, probably around a coffee machine during a pause between two meetings, somebody made an elaborate but not really funny crypto-joke, and it was overheard by somebody else, who did not get it, and proceeded to stir up feelings of anxiety somewhere in the dark corner of a sub-committee. More generally, X.509 makes a lot more sense if you read it as Mary Shelley's draft notes for "Frankenstein", translated for some reason into ancient Ugaritic.

Comment: May I quote that last sentence on my next lectur on X.509?

Comment: Be my guest....

Comment: Making the algorithm part of the signed data is certainly a good idea. This [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/115334/128848) mentions RFC 6211, which is relatively recent and proposes that CMS should do as X.509.